# Why does this syntax rule match numbers in identifiers and how can I fix it?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, color

I wrote a rather simple syntax file, but digits in identifiers get colored:

```
syn match xNumber '\d\+'
```

In `i1` the `1` gets the "numbers" color.

Maybe identifiers need to be matched with higher priority?
Or perhaps the pattern for number needs anchors, like a word beginning/end. I
tried `\b` and `\B`, but then numbers were not highlighted anymore.

Comment: try the following pattern:  `\<\d\+\>`

Answer (score 1):

Vim uses `\<` and `\>` to search for word beginning/end instead of `\b`:

```
syntax match xNumber /\<\d\+\>/
```